# how to change desktop wallpaper?

Tags: delphi, api

How do I change desktop wallpaper?

I tried this

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject); 
var   
  PicPath: String; 
begin 
  PicPath := 'C:\test.bmp';   
  SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pChar(PicPath), SPIF_SENDCHANGE) 
end;
```

But it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried it with D2007 on XP (and also D2009 on Vista), and this code works.
But to catch If and why it is not working, **you should test the result code and get the error from Windows**:

```
  if not SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, pChar(PicPath), SPIF_SENDCHANGE)then
    RaiseLastOSError;
```

In most cases, it will be because the bmp file is not found:

```
System Error.  Code: 2.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this python script:
http://gaze.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gaze/trunk/implementation/src/gazelib/os_interface.py?view=markup

This is the python method that does all the magic. It changes a few registry keys and then calls a system method to update the wallpaper.

```
  103   def set_wallpaper(self, file_path) :
  104       self.__lock.acquire()
  105       # this module is part of python 2.5 by default
  106       import ctypes
  107       import _winreg
  108       reg = _winreg.OpenKey(_winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, self.__REGISTRY_PATH, 0, _winreg.KEY_SET_VALUE)
  109       # First center the image and turn off tiling
  110       _winreg.SetValueEx(reg, "TileWallpaper", 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, "0")
  111       _winreg.SetValueEx(reg, "WallpaperStyle", 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, "0")
  112       # Set the image
  113       _winreg.SetValueEx(reg, "ConvertedWallpaper", 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, os.path.realpath(file_path))
  114       _winreg.SetValueEx(reg, "Wallpaper", 0, _winreg.REG_SZ, self.convert_to_bmp(file_path))
  115       _winreg.CloseKey(reg)
  116       # Notify the changes to the system
  117       func_ret_val = ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(\
  118           self.__SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER,\
  119           0,\
  120           None,\
  121           self.__SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | self.__SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)
  122       assert func_ret_val == 1
  123       self.__lock.release()
```

Answer (score 0):

Check a VB code [here](http://www.programmersheaven.com/mb/Win32API/389985/390897/re-how-can-i-change-the-desktop-wallpaper-programmatically/?S=B20000), it can give you a clue.

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, imageLocation, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE Or SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
Procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  PicPath : string;
begin
  PicPath := 'C:\test.bmp';
  SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, Pointer(PicPath), SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
end;
```